# Mentioning type information in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

How do I specify the type information for the column data to be stored in database in hibernate. I have the below entity class and properties:

```
@Entity
class Employee
{
@column(name="status")
String status;
}
```

Now I want the status to be stored as integer 0 or 1 in the database. Is there a way in hibernate to mention the type as integer in the above case? Any annotation or something?

Comment: If the status should be stored as 0 or 1, then an int, an enum or a boolean would be much more appropriate that a String. In general, the role of Hibernate is not to create the tables. You should do that with a dedicated tool (FlywayDB, liquibase, plain SQL scripts). Hibernate can do it for prototyping though: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition--

Comment: I don't have an option to change the datatype in the entity. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: So, you can change the database schema, but not the entity? Do the right thing, and make whetever necessary to use the right type. Of course, there is https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Converter.html, but really, you should use the right type. Don't pollute all of your application code with bad ly chosen types.

Answer (score 0):

You can set sql type using columnDefinition like this

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
   @Column(name="status", columnDefinition="int default 100")
   String status;
}
```